# Is there an event that fires from a C++ program when a control is about to lose focus?

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

I am trying to fix a validation bug in a MFC `CEdit` control. Currently, validation is performed in an `OnChange` event handler.  But this does not work because it validates data **before** the user is finished entering it.

So, instead, I am trying to validate inside an `OnKillFocus` event handler. If validation fails, then I use `GotoDlgCtrl()` to return focus to the edit box that contained the invalid data.  And when I call `GotoDlgCtrl()`, the kill focus event fires again, and I'm in an infinite loop.

So, I'd like to handle an event that fires just before the control loses focus, so that if I determine that the data is invalid, I can stop focus from leaving and instead get the user to enter correct data.

I know I've seen a Validating event someplace, but that was probably in the .Net world.  But it offers the functionality I'm looking for.

Comment: Before you go too far down this path, please read this article by Raymond Chen of Microsoft: [WM_KILLFOCUS is the wrong time to do field validation](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040419-00/?p=39753/).

Comment: MFC provides a framework for [dialog data validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/dialog-data-validation), that you can customize to meet your specific requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right-click the dialog resource and invoke Class Wizard:

[image: Class Wizard]

Next, go to the Virtual  Functions tab, locate `PreTranslateMessage` and add it:

[image: Virtual Functions]

Then, you can do something like this:

```
BOOL CTestDlgDlg::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg)
{
    if (pMsg->message == WM_CHAR)
    {
        CWnd *pControl = GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT1);
        if (pControl->GetSafeHwnd() == pMsg->hwnd)
        {
            if (pMsg->wParam == _TINT('!'))
            {
                AfxMessageBox(_T("Not allowed ! character"));
                return TRUE;
            }
        }
    }

    return CDialogEx::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg);
}
```

Normally the control is a member variable of type `CEdit` so you could compare against `m_edit.GetSafeHwnd()` instead.

Results:

[image: Result]

## Update

I realise you stated:

> But this does not work because it validates data **before** the user is finished entering it.

You could use `WM_KEYUP` instead:

```
BOOL CTestDlgDlg::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg)
{
    if (pMsg->message == WM_KEYUP)
    {
        CWnd *pControl = GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT1);
        if (pControl->GetSafeHwnd() == pMsg->hwnd)
        {
            CString str;
            GetDlgItemText(IDC_EDIT1, str);
            if (str.Find(_T("!")) >= 0)
            {
                AfxMessageBox(_T("Not allowed ! character"));
                return TRUE;
            }
        }
    }

    return CDialogEx::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg);
}
```

That is give you a chance to validate after the display has been updated.

An alternative it to customize your [`DoDataExchange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class#dodataexchange) handler. In there you can validate as required. Then in your code you simple test the return value of `UpdataData(TRUE)` for `FALSE`.

Comment: How is this answer different than the `OnChange` validation that was already rejected by the OP in the question?

Comment: @MarkRansom Fair point. But all he has to do is change the message surely. WM_KEYUP maybe. Also, I don;t understand why he can't just use the `DoDataExchange` and do customize validation there. OR, he could introduce an "Apply" button and simply test all the values then and handle as needed.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing.  Since the form I want to validate is a property sheet, I get the Apply button automatically.  I already had an OnApply() method.  I just moved all validation there.  I think this was a case of someone trying to get too fancy by validating each keystroke.

Comment: And thanks very much, Mr. Truckle, for the detailed example!